# AWS RDS connection from external client extremely slow

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds

I am currently connecting to an RDS instance (MariaDB) without an issue from within the configured VPC.

I am also connecting to the RDS instance from local clients (external to the VPC) with no connectivity issues but have **serious** issues with SQL execution speeds. It can take up to 20 times longer to execute a query remotely vs locally (an EC2 on same VPC).

I have the Security Group for the RDS instance setup to allow the external IPs as incoming rules and the RDS instance is listening on a non-default port (not 3306).

I cannot think of anything I should be doing differently on the network side of things and I have set `skip-name-resolve=1`, yet the speed is ridiculous.

It has no preference in terms of what the SQL query may be (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE), they all execute slow.

Server RDS is MariaDb 10.1.19 on a db.t2.medium instance.

Client connection is via MySQL .NET Connector and connection string:

```
Server=<ip>;Port=<port>;Database=<dbname>;User ID=<dbuser>;Pooling=true;CharSet=utf8;Password=<dbpass>
```

Client has no connectivity or speed issues when DB in not an RDS (local MySQL).

I have seen various network related issues popping up now and then (connection stream dropped) but nothing serious apart from that, just very slow.

Any pointers on how to at least determine where the problem is?

The scenario I am trying to achieve (with acceptable speeds) is described here (albeit vague in their instructions):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario4

[image]

Comment: Is the query returning lots of data, or is it (for example) just a one-line response?

Comment: Multiple queries (thousands) some small some with results and some in transactions. Never too much data though (below the 100 rows)

Comment: What is an example of the time taken for a single query to execute in each scenario?

Comment: 0.4 sec on local connection 0.36 sec to RDS

Comment: Clarification: What is the time taken for a given query if you connect (1) from within the VPC and (2) from external to the VPC?

Comment: (1) takes 0.4 sec (2) takes 0.36

Comment: The Question says "It can take up to 20 times longer to execute a query remotely vs locally (an EC2 on same VPC)." -- that is not reflected in that per-query timing. Is that timing based on the time from when your client sends the request until it gets the result, or is it the time reported by the database? Where is the "20 times longer"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161780/discussion-between-george-and-john-rotenstein).

Comment: any resolve on this? it's not limited to mysql/mariadb; i have both rds systems, and when connecting w/ local code; it takes eons to run. however, it's only through code. i can always connect remotely w/ workbench, mssql enterprise, etc. w/ no latency issues.